# Updating HBase from PySpark using Phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hbase, upsert, apache-phoenix

I am trying to read from and write to HBase from PySpark using Phoenix Connectors.

I have seen the example code in https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html
Replicating the sample code here for easy reference:

```
df.write \
  .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("table", "TABLE1") \
  .option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181") \
  .save()
```

I have been able to both read and write from pyspark into hbase. However, this example only gives the mode as "overwrite", which means the whole table will be overwritten. However, I want an option to append data or update (upsert) into HBase from PySpark.

Most examples I see are scala based and I am not able to get any clear documentation on pyspark support.

Any sample code for the same or insights on what other modes are supported by Phoenix Connectors, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After I tried various combinations of data insert and update with the same "overwrite" mode, what I realise is that this same mode acts as "append" as well as "update".

Is the key already exists in HBase, the data gets updated, if the key does not exist, the data gets inserted.

However, if I try to delete data by "overwriting" with a new dataframe that has some data removed, it does not seems to work. So, in effect, it is doing upserts and not overwrites, as the word seems to suggest.

Comment: df.write.mode("append").options(catalog = catalog, newtable = 4).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save()

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark SQL in general does not support updates / upserts. Since it doesn't provide atomic transactions across executors, and updates are typically not idempotent, it would be easy to end up with corrupt state, which might be really hard to recover from in case of large dataset.

Sometimes users use `RDD` / `mapPartitions` to manually push data, but it makes more sense to push your data to a queuing, like Kafka, and use client with higher granularity and means to gracefully recover from errors.

Comment: Hi @user9182321, Your input seems to suggest that it is more of a Spark way of working by design, though HBase itself provides upsert options... Is that right? 
That seems a bit strange as I see things evolving beyond that. 

Of late, Hive is also beginning to support updates through ACID transaction support. I have tried and seen that I can update hive tables from Spark. (though the way it internally propagates is through compaction and hence takes a visible time period to show the updates). 

So, I was expecting HBase also to be updatable from PySpark, considering HBase supports updates